# AWS error when running glue job Failed to sanitize XML

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Has anyone seen this error before? Here is the important part of the ETL that could be causing the problem. This transformation needs to occur for 500+ million records. Which have been crawled.

```
  , cast(unix_timestamp (to_timestamp( replace( substr(reads.`end-date-time`
                                      , 1, 23),'T',' ')
                              , 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS' ) )
          as bigint ) `Timestamp`
  , case trim( reads.`vee-value` )
      when '' then reads.value
      else 
        case round( reads.value, 4 )
          when cast( reads.`vee-value` as double ) then value
        else
          cast( reads.`vee-value` as double )
        end 
    end
    Consumption
```

Error
An error occurred while calling o67.getDynamicFrame. com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to sanitize XML document destined for handler class com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser$ListObjectsV2Handler

Answer (score 1):

That looks like an Out Of Memory (OOM) error. Do you have run metrics enabled? If so I would check out the memory. You are most likely overloading the driver. One thing you could try is use S3ListImplementation which is a more efficient way to list S3 files, helping to decrease driver memory use.

In this blog, scroll down to #2: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/optimize-memory-management-in-aws-glue/

If you are using from_options it will look like this:

```
    DataSource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
        format_options={"withHeader": True, "separator": separator, "quoteChar": quoteChar},
        connection_type="s3",
        format="csv",
        connection_options={"paths": inputPathList, **"useS3ListImplementation": True,** "recurse": True},
        transformation_ctx="DataSource0"
    )
```

If you are using from_catalog it will look like this:

```
    DataSource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
        database = "database-name",
        table_name= "table-name",
        additional_options={**"useS3ListImplementation": True**},
        transformation_ctx="DataSource0"
    )
```

If this doesn't work I would recommend using a bounded execution, here's a doc explaining this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/bounded-execution.html
Basically what it does is controls the # of files that are processed during each execution. Note: Glue bookmarks must be enabled for this to work.